# window moveTo placing window at half of the passed arguments in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, popup, popupwindow

I'm seeing some strange behavior with pop up windows on FireFox (93.0) on Mac, when trying to change the position of an opened pop up it places it at half the position I assign. For example, if I create a pop up window like this:

```js
const test = window.open('assets/test.html', 'test', 'width=200,height=200,top=0,left=0')
```

It correctly opens a 200x200 sized window at the top left corner of my screen. If I check it's x coordinate in the console by entering `test.screenX` it correctly returns `0`. Then if I try to move the window like this:

```js
test.moveTo(300, 0)
```

...it places the window at `150` pixels from the left. I've confirmed this by printing `test.screenX` to the console which returns `150`. Similarly, if I try `test.moveTo(500, 0)` then `test.screenX` will be `250`, if I try `test.moveTo(10, 0)` then `test.screenX` will be `5`, etc.

This does not happen in Chrome, where if I try `test.moveTo(500, 0)` then `test.screenX` will be `500` as expected.

Is this just a FireFox bug? Is there some way around this? The bug is consistent enough that I could target the browser and theoretically double the value if a user is on FireFox, but this feels like a very dangerous hack to me. Is there something going on here I'm missing or not understanding about pop ups?

Comment: What version of FF?  Can you post a short runnable code snippet we can test

Comment: @Phaelaxz FF 93.0 (64-bit), i tried creating a fiddle but the nature of popups complicates this (i need to run a local server with both the main html file and the test html file in it), but the error should be reproducible by running a local server in a directory with two html pages and running the code posted here in the console of the main html page (editing the URL to the popup html file to match yours of course)

Comment: I'm running FF 84 and window.open won't even work for me. I read a few articles that said FF 76 had changed how it handles window.open(). And it looks like they've continued to change it with each version.